# Laravel 5.5.14 - Installing on shared host with Softaculous

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install Laravel 5.5.14 on a shared host. (5.4 worked fine for my sub domain on same host)

So i installed Laravel with softaculous and whenever i go to my domain it throws a HTTP 500 Error.

I have no idea why it's doing it as Laravel 5.4 works on the same host but on a subdomain.

***EDIT:*** **AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pitpitpit/domains/pit-pit-pit.nl/public_html/.htaccess** is the apache error log error.

htaccess can be found here:  pastebin.com/V6bYJ0Wr

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: Whats the servers error log show?

Comment: Where do i find that again? i cant remember.

Comment: Also, please include the folder structure where you want your laravel application installed

Comment: Its in `/var/log/apache/error.log` but maybe not for you, maybe its 1 up from your allocated webroot. The error log will tell you why you got a 500.. there is many reasons it could throw one, so your need to find that out before we can help.

Comment: I cant find that error log, i've however found a laravel error log which is totally empty.

Comment: Whos your host?

Comment: Versio.nl (dutch host)

Comment: From control panel, Site Summary / Statistics / Logs -> Full error log

Comment: AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pitpitpit/domains/pit-pit-pit.nl/public_html/.htaccess Is what it says

Comment: The htaccess at that location is generated by laravel itself and it contains : https://pastebin.com/V6bYJ0Wr

Answer (score 0):

add the .htaccess file with codes like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It must be in the root file, not the laravel public folder.